# Google Cloud - Pytorch Deep Learning VM - Error: 'module' object has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I have tried GCP following these tutorial https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/pytorch_start_instance and I've tried to run my code using a GPU TeslaK80. It gives me the following AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'. Days before I had another VM and it worked fine. I had create another Deep Learning VM and now it gives me that error. I don't understand why it's failing now.

These is my stacktrace:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cc76841a4302> in <module>()
     45 # from config_training import config as config_training
     46 torch.manual_seed(0)
---> 47 torch.cuda.set_device(0)
     48 
     49 model = import_module(args.model)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.pyc in set_device(device)
    262     device = _get_device_index(device)
    263     if device >= 0:
--> 264         torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
    265 
    266 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'
```